# How Can I check that my paypal adaptive payment is working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have created an paypal adaptive transaction system. Using sandbox for testing my code.
But, For checking that my code is working for successful transaction which account be used for buying in test mode ?

Already, I have tried to buy using my sandbox business account credentials but it say wrong email or password . Could you suggest me about it ?

I added a figure in below:

[image]

I am awaiting for an affirmative response from you. How can I check it?

Answer (score 2):

You said that you are using sandbox environment for testing paypal transactions, but I can see that you webpage it's on paypal. Therefore any sandbox accounts won't work on the sandbox environment.

You need two accounts created in sandbox:
one for business ( type of account needs to be business )
one for purchases ( type of account needs to be personal )

Also, make sure that any form action attribute points to sanbox.paypal.com not paypal.com

Hope that helps

EDIT: you can make purchases using the personal account

Comment: I have added the wrong image. Now it is fixed. Please, see my edit. Ans suggest me.

Comment: "You need two accounts created in sandbox: one for business ( type of account needs to be business ) one for purchases ( type of account needs to be personal )"
---------------- Can I use an email to create both type of account.


Both account wil be created in sandbox ?

Comment: Firstly, you need to create a developer account on paypal (developer.paypal.com). After you log in go to Applications->Sanbox accounts and create two accounts. These accounts don't need a real email. There are used by sandbox environment for testing purposes. In here you create those two types of accounts that I mentioned above